# Replace CSV delimiter by pipe character

Tags: linux, csv

I need to change CSV delimiter -> `','` (comma) to `'|'` (pipe).

I'm not able to blindly replace all comma characters by pipe character since some values contain comma characters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use csvkit, you can change your delimiter safely:

https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
csvformat -D '[your delimiter here]' [file name]
```